What do the trees in the Garden represent?
In Genesis 2, God plants a garden in Eden for man to tend and cultivate. At the center of the garden are the Tree of Life and the Tree of the Knowledge of Good & Evil. What do these trees represent and how are they cultivated?
I see a strong correlation between the account of the garden and Moses' speech in Deuteronomy 30. The two trees represent two choices presented to man - one leading to life and the other to death (Genesis 2:17). If Adam & Eve had done as commanded then they could have enjoyed the fruit of the tree of life, but by choosing to disobey they were barred from the tree of life and thus would die.

Deutoronomy 30:15-20  “See, I have placed before you today life and happiness, and death and adversity, 16 in that I am commanding you today to love the Lord your God, to walk in His ways and to keep His commandments, His statutes, and His judgments, so that you may live and become numerous, and that the Lord your God may bless you in the land where you are entering to take possession of it. 17 But if your heart turns away and you will not obey, but allow yourself to be led astray and you worship other gods and serve them, 18 I declare to you today that you will certainly perish. You will not prolong your days in the land where you are crossing the Jordan to enter and take possession of it. 19 I call heaven and earth to witness against you today, that I have placed before you life and death, the blessing and the curse. So choose life in order that you may live, you and your descendants, 20 by loving the Lord your God, by obeying His voice, and by holding close to Him; for this is your life and the length of your days, so that you may live in the land which the Lord swore to your fathers, to Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, to give them.”

Based upon this correlation, it seems that Life is found / cultivated through obedience to God; had Adam and Eve obeyed God then they would not have been bared from the Tree of Life.
On the other hand, the Tree of the Knowledge of Good & Evil seems to figure the Law? For through it, man becomes aware of his sin and it produces guilt and shame and fear of the Lord's presence. Atonement becomes a necessity in order to address man's guilty conscience so that he can once more appear before God without fear.
Yet is it not through knowledge of the Law that we may obey God and thus cultivate life?
Does death then become a prerequisite to life? (EDIT: Leaving this here as part of my thought process, but don't answer it here. I will create a separate question for it later).
Or perhaps, continuing the correlation with Deuteronomy 30, it is not the knowledge that brought death so much as it was the fact that they were "led astray and worshiped other gods (the serpent / Egypt?) and served them."

1] You claim a correlation  between the trees in Eden and Deuteronomy 30 without explaining it. Can you please edit the explanation into the question.
2] You claim based on the correlation that the Tree of the Knowledge of Good & Evil represents death.
Without convincing evidence for the correlation, I cannot accept the premise of your question.

Related, possible dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/133733/31534

The questions you are asking in this are very big! It is indeed true that the tree of knowledge is associated with the process of learning out the law, and the tree of life represents true, undebateable knowledge (which makes your word "obedience" ring true). That knowledge of the law is the ticket to obedience - that's a huge question, as is the question about death being a prerequisite to life. I suggest this question get broken up or focussed. My 2 cents

@AvrohomYitzchok I added a bit more explanation to the correlation I see between Deut 30 and the Garden; let me know if you have any further questions about this correlation that can help refine the question. As for the Tree of the Knowledge of Good & Evil leading to death: "but from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not [o]eat, for on the day that you eat from it you will certainly die." (Genesis 2:17)

@RabbiKaii Good points. I think I will move the question about death being a prerequisite to life into a separate question; perhaps find some more related scripture.
